# How to change the phone number format of call permission popup Swift

Tags: ios, swift4, call, phone-call, ios-permissions

I am making a call to a number and it is working fine. Is there a way to change the number format  of the permission asking popup in swift ?

Here is my code:

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://\("
        8680047015 ")"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

As of now the popup is as follows. I would like to change it to 868-004-7015.[image].

While trying a US number, it is showing as 1234 - 567890. How formatting is happening?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding country code like `URL(string: "tel:1-868-004-7015")` ? There is a [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) documentation for phone numbers.

Comment: No. I am not adding any country code. passing the number only.